# Can a covering index be a target of a foreign key constraint?

Tags: postgresql

Lets say I have tables like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  id,
  key UNIQUE,
  a,
  b,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE t2
(
  id,
  t1_key,
  b,
  CONSTRAINT t2_key_b_fk 
    FOREIGN KEY (t1_key, b)
    REFERENCES t1(key, b)
);
```

The constraint `t2_key_b_fk` will fail because I don't have an index on `t1(key, b)`.

Adding this to `t1` solves the problem:

```
CONSTRAINT t1_key_b_uk
  UNIQUE (key, b)
```

But now I feel like I'm doubling up on indexes. I'm effectively indexing `key` twice.

I was hoping this would work:

```
CREATE TABLE t1
(
  id,
  key,
  a,
  b,
  ...
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX t1_key_uk ON t1(key) INCLUDE (b)
```

And notice I've removed the UNIQUE constraint on `key` in the create table statement, because this uniqueness is now enforced by `t1_key_uk`.

However, even with this setup, the `t2_key_b_fk` foreign key constraint fails to create, even though *I think* it now has enough information.

Yes, column `b` is redundant between columns. And yes, I'm using foreign keys to enforce that consistency. It would be better if `b` was only in `t1` and not in `t2`, but there's a requirement that it's in all tables (in short, `b` determines what client owns the data).

Is there a way I could get this setup working, both allowing for the `(key, b)` foreign key and forcing uniqueness on `key` directly, whilst only creating one index?

Answer (score 1):

No, you need the second unique index, even if it is redundant as such.